# If-else if statement not working properly

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to make a multiplication game for my sister, but my code doesn't go through if-else statements properly. I have no idea why this is so. Can someone 
tell what I am doing wrong?

```
from random import randint

print "Welcome to Multiplication Practice."
print "\n-------"

correct = 0

wrong = 0

while wrong<3:

    a = randint(1,9)
    b = randint(1,9)
    print "What is %s x %s?" %(a,b)
    c = a * b
    action = raw_input("> ")
    if action == c:
        print "correct!"
        correct +=1

    elif  action != c:
        print "Wrong!"
        wrong +=1

    else:
        print "Invalid answer."

print correct 

print wrong
```

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string, multiplication returns a number. They'll never be equal.

Comment: try `action = int(raw_input("> "))`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks! Anything else i overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raw_input` always returns a string
You need to convert it into the type you're comparing it to, in this case
`int(raw_input("> "))`

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` returns a string. This will never compare equal to a number. You need to convert the entered string to a number:

```
action = int(raw_input("> "))
```